# Lua: Avoid overloading of pcall and Lua callstack

Tags: c++, lua, access-violation, callstack, stack-corruption

I have a program that performs very fast-paced calls to a Lua script using `lua_pcall`. It seems if the program calls the lua script too fast, things will foul up and cause access violations in the most random of places.

I've tried mutexes and even enabled SEH exceptions with try/catch to no avail. Error functions are in place and I'm checking all of the approprate return codes; the problem is an actual access violation deep within the pcall, not a safely handled Lua error.

A lot of the time the break occurs in `luaV_execute`, but sometimes it's in other random places. I've checked to make sure all parameters pushed to the stack are valid.

Is there a way to force Lua to complete a call before returning, or some way to ensure the call stack doesn't get corrupted?

Comment: This seems mildly surprising; I've not come across anything similar in my own projects which do occasionally involve a large number of sequential calls to `lua_pcall` without issue... but I'm using linux and "SEH" suggests you're using windows. I'd be inclined to blame threading; presumably you've ruled that out?

Comment: I am using threading, but the particular calls are occurring on the main thread, the same thread the lua state is getting created in. Is there something I need to do to make Lua more thread-safe?

Comment: I am also pretty sure this is not a problem with Lua itself. My guess is that `malloc` and `free` functions are not thread-safe on your platform. Is this possible? BTW, can you describe your platform?

Comment: Windows 7 x64 visual studio 2012 runtimes (MSVC 11, dynamic MT). Lua 5.2.1

Comment: You say "the particular calls"... does that mean that some calls to the runtime are done on other threads? Or do you enforce that all lua state access is done only through a single thread for its lifetime?

Comment: Now that you mention it, yes there are other calls that are done in other threads. For some reason that didn't occur to me at all (must be tired). The state must be getting fouled up.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to allow cross-thread calling in Lua? Do I need to create a second state? Do I need to channel all calls through the main thread (where it was created)? If I create another state, does that mean I need to re-load all of the scripts for that state (or is there a copy state mechanism)?

Comment: I suspect that so long as you have a global access lock that you must acquire before accessing the lua state, you should be fine. Do any of your lua scripts access objects which are 'live' in threads other than the calling one? That also has the potential to cause confusing state corruptions.

Comment: If by "live" you mean actively referenced/mutated, then yes.

Comment: The mutex I applied was only around the call that was failing. I will try to put it into the call function that wraps the C functions that does the calling.

Comment: Rook: Woohoo, that worked! I was afraid it was going to cause deadlock, but it didn't. Thinking about it now, I don't see why it would. Mind posting an answer suggesting a global lock on the state? I'll accept it :]

Comment: So long as your C++ objects are thread safe you're probably fine. I've had some issues with userdata instances outliving their underlying C++ object instances which resulted in very cryptic errors, but this might not be an issue for you.

Comment: No I've taken pretty good care knowing the lifetimes of objects as far as lua/C++ interactions go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the Lua system as a whole is fully re-entrant, individual `lua_State` instances are not in themselves thread safe.

If you're accessing a `lua_State` from multiple threads, you should use a mutex or other locking mechanism to ensure that only one thread at a time can manipulate that state. Simultaneous accesses could easily result in the sort of corruption you're seeing.

If you're working with multiple `lua_State` instances, each state can have its own access lock; you don't need a single global lock for the whole Lua runtime.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you for working through it with me; things are working perfectly!